# NEO4J JDBC Add relationship error

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-java-api

I am trying to add a relationship to nodes using Neo4J JDBC driver and have formed the following query :

```
MATCH (node1:USER {fameId : 'test1'}),(node2:BEAM {eventUId : 'E000000016'}) 
CREATE (node1)-[r:PERFORMED{type:'test'}]->(node2)`
```

When I try to run this query using:

```
mConnection.createStatement().execute("MATCH (node1:USER {fameId : 'test1'}),(node2:BEAM {eventUId : 'E000000016'}) CREATE (node1)-[r:PERFORMED{type:'test'}]->(node2)")
```

It gives me the following error :

`Error executing query MATCH (node1:USER {fameId : 'test1'}),(node2:BEAM {eventUId : 'E000000016'}) CREATE (node1)-[r:PERFORMED{type:'test'}]->(node2)
MATCH (node1:USER {fameId : 'test2'}),(node2:BEAM {eventUId : 'E000000016'}) CREATE (node1)-[r:PERFORMED{type:'test'}]->(node2)
 with params {}`

Please help. I am not able to proceed further :(

Comment: Can you see any detail of that exception?

Comment: no...unfortunately, this is the only error I am getting. :( that is why I am also not able to debug

Comment: Can you share your full code that you try to run?